# Google Sheets API v4 with oAuth 2.0 server to server authentication using a service account in javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I searched everywhere and can't find an example to follow.

I have a private google sheet. I use the data from the google sheet to populate various charts using Google Visualization API on a simple webpage using javascript.

Currently each user has to authorize (via oauth flow) to see the data in the charts. Users only look at the charts, they don't modify them so there's no reason for my web app to have access to each user Google account.

I'd like to eliminate the user authentication portion and instead authorize the server to authenticate with the private google sheet via a google service account and server-to-server Oauth while keeping the actual spreadsheet private.

Steps I took:
I created a service account in the Google Developers Console
Saved the .json file with the private key, public key, id, etc.

I tried to follow the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) but there's no example that uses javascript.
I'm also not sure why the code exposes the p12 file that contains the private key.

The example that was authorizing users via oAuth flow to access the spreadsheet is pretty simple, and this is what I was doing:

```
function initClient() {
    var API_KEY = 'myapikey';

    var CLIENT_ID = 'myid'; 
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    }).then(function() {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
        updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
}

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
   }

function updateSignInStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
   //do stuff
    drawGID()
    }
    else{

    }
}

function handleSignInClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

function handleSignOutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

//draw all the charts
function drawGID() {
        var params = { 
            valueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE",
            spreadsheetId: 'myspreadsheetID',
            range: 'MySpreadsheetRange!A:AX', 
        };
        var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params);
        request.then(function(response) {
            //do various stuff with the data from response
            var dataTable = response.getDataTable();

          });
          }
```

Comment: were you able to find the solution to this? I am stuck at the same place...